# Want to inject some services into a WebHostBuilder for testing. Can I do it after WebHost has been started? Should I change test initialization?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, mocking, xunit

I'm working in a very large existing codebase where it's hard for me to fully refactor `MyTestFixture`. Tests are setup like this:

**MyTestFixture.cs**

```
public class MyTestFixture: IDisposable
{
    IWebHost host;
    public MyTestFixture()
    {
        this.host = CreateWebHost();
    }
    
    public CreateWebHost()
    {
        return new WebHostBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices()
        .Build();
    }
}
```

**MyTest1.cs**

```
public class MyTest1 : IClassFixture<MyTestFixture>
{
    MyTestFixture testFixture;
    public MyTest1(MyTestFixture testFixture)
    {
        this.testFixture = testFixture;
    }
}
```

I have some cases where I need to mock one of the services in the webhost. I need a full E2E and it's too difficult to mock all the individual components up, I really just want a full E2E run where one small thing is mocked. I'm trying to figure out the best to get a mocked service injected into the webhost.

I see I can do something like `this.testFixture.host.Services.GetRequiredService<ISomeService>();` but I don't see any way to add in a service. Is there any way to do that?

My alternative solution has been to add a new virtual property to MyTestFixture, `Mocks` that's a list of objects. I inject the list of objects into the services during `CreateWebHost`. Then in `MyTest1` I create a new fixture that inherits from `MyTestFixture` and overrides `Mocks`. It's a little messy though because I don't see a good way to retrieve the mocks in my actual test cases without searching through the full list.

```
public class OverrideClass : MyTestFixture
{
    public OverrideClass(): Base(){}
    public override List<Object> Mocks { get; set; } = new List<Object>()
    {
        A.Fake<ISomeService1>(),
        A.Fake<ISomeService2>(),
    }
}

public class MyTest1 : IClassFixture<OverrideClass>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar, but use an `Action<IServiceCollection>` in the base class that derived classes can override. This delegate is then invoked when the test server is created, using the `ConfigureTestServices()` method on the `IWebHostBuilder` ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-8.0#inject-mock-services)):

```csharp
class TestBaseClass {
   protected Action<IServiceCollection>? ConfigureAdditionalTestServices { get; set; }

   // Register the creation of the test server as factory method
   // so that derived test classes can set-up fake services before
   // creation
   Fixture.Register(() =>
      new WebApplicationFactory<TProgram>()
         .WithWebHostBuilder(builder => {
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services => {
               // Give tests a chance to add specific services
               ConfigureAdditionalTestServices?.Invoke(services);
            });
         })
```

As long as derived test classes set the delegate before they resolve an instance of the test server, the delegate will be executed and the test-specific services will be registered.

This means that you only need to register the services you want to replace on a per-test basis. All other services use appropriate defaults.

Using the delegate approach, rather than a generic list of objects to be registered, provides more power when you need to register factory methods rather than just an instance.